# Using Segmented Control to perform segues

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am Trying to Perform Segues with Segmented Control Buttons. 
//Segmented Control

```
@IBOutlet weak var SegmentControl: UISegmentedControl!
@IBAction func Segment(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
switch SegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
case 0:
    shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier("hello1", sender: self)
case 1:
    shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier("hello2", sender: self)
default:
    break;
}
}
```

Although The App Build Well, When i Click one of Segments the App doesn't perform the segue.Im kind of new to swift , I'm not sure if this works,however its worth the try. Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("hello1", sender: self)
```

instead of

```
shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier("hello1", sender: self)
```

So your code should like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var SegmentControl: UISegmentedControl!
@IBAction func Segment(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
switch SegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
case 0:
    performSegueWithIdentifier("hello1", sender: self)
case 1:
    performSegueWithIdentifier("hello2", sender: self)
default:
    break;
}
}
```

Comment: more than glad to do that but i have an 8 minute countdown , bear with me.